# XDP/eBPF Error when include iphdr pointer to struct

Tags: c, xdp-bpf

I met some problem while code XDP/eBPF for Firewall, When I save pointer of iphdr to struct, compiler return errors.

Problem code:

```
struct Packet {
 struct xdp_md* ctx;
 struct ethhdr* ether;
 struct iphdr* ip;
 struct def_tcphdr* tcp;
 struct udphdr* udp;
 __u32 rule_version;
};

SEC("xdp_prog")
int xdp_main(struct xdp_md* ctx) {
  void *data = (void *)(long)ctx->data;
  void *data_end = (void *)(long)ctx->data_end;
  struct ethhdr* eth = (struct ethhdr*)data;
  struct iphdr* iph = NULL;
  if (eth + 1 > (struct ethhdr *)data_end)
  { 
    return XDP_DROP;
  }
  if (unlikely(eth->h_proto != bpf_htons(ETH_P_IP) && eth->h_proto != bpf_htons(ETH_P_IPV6)))
  {
    return XDP_DROP;
  }
  if (eth->h_proto == bpf_htons(ETH_P_IPV6)) // DROP IPV6
  {
    return XDP_DROP;
  }
  iph = (data + sizeof(struct ethhdr));
  if (unlikely(iph + 1 > (struct iphdr *)data_end))
  {
    return XDP_DROP;
  }
  struct Packet packet;
    packet.ctx = ctx;
    packet.ether = eth;
  if (iph != NULL)
    packet.ip = iph; // Problems here, without this code, compile without error.
  int ret = 0;
  ret = Process_Policy(&packet);

  return ret;
}
```

Error text:

```
error: <unknown>:0:0: in function xdp_main i32 (%struct.xdp_md*): A call to built-in function 'abort' is not supported.
```

I tried to find out same problems in google and duckduckgo.. but no case like me.

Comment: Could you provide the definition of `Process_Policy` or a minimal reproducible example?